# CakePHP Dynamic conditions in Query

Tags: php

I am doing a search function in cakephp. Searching is based on number of parameters like price between particular range, particular category , created date etc. Most of parameters are not mandatory.How can I specify these conditions in single where clause(not mandatory fields). The number of values may change like product based on different category .

Answer (score 0):

Since the conditions are passed as an array you can build this array dynamically (however it is you decide which fields are part of the conditions) and then use that variable as the conditions.

E.g. this query

```
$cheapJacuzzis = $this->Item->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Item.price <' => 300,
            'Item.category' => 'Jacuzzi'
        ),
        'order' => 'Item.price ASC'
    )
);
```

Becomes

```
$conditions = array(
    'Item.price <' => 300,
    'Item.category' => 'Jacuzzi'
);

$cheapJacuzzis = $this->Item->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => 'Item.price ASC'
    )
);
```

This can be done with all the cases you need to dynamically build an array cakephp asks for as a parameter set.